# Как сделать пошаговую выборку выборку mysql для конкретной таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Есть вот такая таблица (рис. 1) которая представляет из себя чат между двумя собеседниками.
Необходимо сделать выборку так что бы получилось увидеть последние сообщения из каждой группы двух собеседников (рис. 2)
Сложность заключается в том что user_id 0 и user_id 1 это один user_id.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
рис. 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
рис. 2

Comment: sender 3 - recipient 0
sender 1 - recipient 3
это чат между двумя пользователями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Необходимо сделать выборку так что бы получилось увидеть последние сообщения из каждой группы двух собеседников

Получите в подзапросе время последнего сообщения для каждого диалога:

```
SELECT LEAST(sender,recipient) collocutor1
     , GREATEST(sender,recipient) collocutor2
     , MAX(ordering_time) last_post_time
FROM chat_table
GROUP BY LEAST(sender,recipient) 
       , GREATEST(sender,recipient)
```

и используйте его для отбора последнего сообщения диалога.

> Сложность заключается в том что user_id 0 и user_id 1 это один user_id.

Значит, дополнительно

```
CASE sender WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE sender END
```

и то же для recipient.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, про CASE не знал. Как вы дошли до того что нужно использовать в этом случае функции LEAST, GREATEST?

Comment: Есть два значения, которые могут дублироваться в прямом и обратном порядке. Нужно свернуть оба таких варианта в один. Простейший метод - сортировка. Сортировка двух значений - просто выбор большего (либо меньшего) из них. А это выполняют именно использованные функции.